# Check if a string contains terms with numbers in them

Tags: java, regex, string, text, split

Based on my knowledge, there isn't any function to recognize terms which contain number in them. I have a corpus that there are some sentences like:

**Alice2B Visum 7/2 Dann 394–3973-3 ging sie nach Hollywood dort als 25.1 Drehbuchautorin arbeiten Kurz 2006 nach ihrer 329–49 Ankunft lernte sie den Filmregisseur 02/ayn Cecil**

I need to just maintain words and remove all numbers or terms with number in them. For this example, the output should be like this:

**Visum Dann ging sie nach Hollywood dort als Drehbuchautorin arbeiten Kurz nach ihrer Ankunft lernte sie den Filmregisseur Cecil**

I am looking for something that works in **Java**. Any information on this topic is appreciated.

Comment: what should happen if there is a number in the URL..? should it be removed?

Comment: Also post [mcve]

Comment: No. It should be remain

Comment: If the URL contains a non encoded space and if the terms have number in them? it is hard to distinguish when URL contains space and you don't want to remove those numbers

Comment: If we don't think about url, Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex to find the terms those contain numbers

```
\S*\d+\S*
```

then removes them (simple you can use `String.replaceAll(regex)`). If you want to handle url separately you may need to find another way to detect them

**NB:** verify the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/4IG6Lr/1)

Answer (score 1):

Split it into substrings (String.split()) and then loop through the substrings to see if they contain numbers (String.matches(regex))

Comment: I need the regex. What regex should I use?

Comment: Regular expression. This should clarify : https://www.moreofless.co.uk/check-string-contains-number-using-java/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split(" +"));
list.replaceAll(s -> s.matches(".*\\d+.*") ? "" : s);
final String result = StringUtils.join(list, ' ').replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Comment: splitting on single space might not always work. corpus data can contain  different number of spaces as term delimeter

Comment: You are already using `+` which represents `{1,}` so why not `*` instead of `{0,}`?

Comment: Oops, didn't know about that one. Edited

Comment: but this should be an one liner solution. splitting all terms and joining them again all together is an over kill

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this. Maybe it helps others. Thank you @Shafin Mahmud and @Björn Schönrock.

```
final String inputText = "Alice2B Visum 7/2 Dann 394–3973-3 ging sie nach Hollywood dort als 25.1 Drehbuchautorin arbeiten Kurz 2006 nach ihrer 329–49 Ankunft lernte sie den Filmregisseur 02/ayn Cecil";

for (String t : inputText.split(" +")) {
    if (t.split("\\S*\\d+\\S*").length>0)
       System.out.println(t);
}
```

or something like this:

```
final String inputText = "Alice2B Visum 7/2 Dann 394–3973-3 ging sie nach Hollywood dort als 25.1 Drehbuchautorin arbeiten Kurz 2006 nach ihrer 329–49 Ankunft lernte sie den Filmregisseur 02/ayn Cecil";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[0-9]" );
for (String t : inputText.split(" +")) {
    if (!p.matcher(t).find())
       System.out.println(t);
}
```